# Why is decoding and encoding Strings in java not always symetric?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am confused about the decoding and encoding on Java String.

Now I hava a string variable "中国", means China in Chinese, which is contained in Chinese native charset GB2312, and also in Unicode.

So what the difference between the following ??

```
val f = "中国"

println(new String(f.getBytes("GB2312"),"GB2312"))

println(new String((new  String(f.getBytes("GB2312"),"UTF8")).getBytes("UTF8"),"GB2312") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It behaves like this because the output of `new String(x, "UTF8").getBytes("UTF8")` will only be `x` if `x` is actually a valid byte representation of a UTF-8 String. Otherwise according to the [javadoc for `String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset))

> This method always replaces malformed-input and unmappable-character sequences with this charset's default replacement string.

The default character for UTF-8 is � (bit representation `11101111  10111111  10111101`). `f.getBytes("GB2312")` returns the following sequence of bits: `11010110  11010000  10111001  11111010`. As in one invalid character, followed by `11010000  10111001` or й and then another invalid character. The output of `new String(f.getBytes("GB2312"),"UTF8")` is therefor �й�, or converted to binary form, `11101111  10111111  10111101  11010000  10111001  11101111  10111111  10111101`.

`11010110` and `11111010` are invalid because any sequence of bytes beginning with a byte of the form `11xxxxxx` must be followed by one or more bytes in the form `10xxxxxx` (the exact number depends on the number of `1`'s at the start of the first number). See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) for more details about the UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, `new String(s.getBytes("UTF8"),"GB2312") )` doesn't do what you think it does. (I can't know what you think it does but nothing good can come from it so I assume.)

It means: Encode text from a string using UTF-8 then take those bytes and decode them as if they were text encoded using GB2313.